# looping for a series

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this question:

> Write a program to display the sum of the series  1+1/2+2/3+3/4+...
>   +(n-1)/n (using for loop).

I did not understand the series well, kindly explaint it for me if n = 6. (no need for coding).

Comment: Well... which algorithm?

Comment: @Adban: i.e. "tell me how to do it?" No. Isn't that what your tutor is for?

Comment: Read up on "loop invariant". Even if you are an experienced programmer who would find the stated problem fairly easy to resolve, but you aren't familiar with "loop invariant", you would start looking at loops differently when you read up on "loop invariant".

Comment: I can code it easly, my problem is that the series somehow was vague. that is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For n = 6, you need to calculate 1 + (1/2) + (2/3) + (3/4) + (4/5) + (5/6)

Answer (score 3):

The question is asking you to fill the details in to the following program:

```
sum = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
    sum += ???
}
return sum;
```

where ??? should give you the following values:

```
i | ???
-------
1 |  1
2 | 1/2
3 | 2/3
4 | 3/4
5 | 4/5
6 | 5/6
.
.
.
n | (n-1)/n
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. The biggest hint is the nth term itself : `(n-1)/n`

Except the first term, every other term can be represented by an expression of the form of `(i-1)/i`, which means the algorithm boils down to this:

```
double sum  = 1.0; //first term
for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; ++i) //2nd to nth term!
   sum += (i-1.0)/i;
```

Why did I write `(i-1.0)` instead of `(i-1)`?

You need to figure that out yourself, as I already have explained and written almost the whole code.

Comment: This question was tagged as homework (so working out all the details is perhaps not in his best interest).

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop that evaluates `(n-1)/n` for each value of `n` and adds the outcome to some variable.
That "some variable" is the answer.

Set `n=6`

Comment: @yi_H or `n=0` for that matter..! what's your point? He wants to understand the algorithm, not code in C++ that takes care of DBZ..

Comment: since loop starts from n=1, I don't see how n=0 is relevant.. but n=1 is, because it gives the wrong result for the first element of the series.

Answer (score 0):

The final term of the series can also be written as `n / (n + 1)` where `n` is a value that iterates.